# Mono on Mac OS X - Illegal Instruction 4

Tags: c#, macos, mono

I'm running a C# console application on Mac OS X Lion through Terminal.app via mono. However many of my longer running scripts eventually end with a single line that says "illegal instruction 4". There is no other debugging or error information.

Does anyone know how I can try to track down the cause of the error?

Thank you,
Chris

Comment: Mono version? You should try to debug first, and then post more information within the question, http://www.mono-project.com/Debugging. Otherwise, nobody can help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused because I was using portions of the .NET library that were not ported to Mono. In my case it was the SqlBulkCopy Class (`System.Data.SqlClient`).